# GSM CMS Error 512 when sending SMS

Tags: sms, gsm, sms-gateway

I'm programming an app to send SMS through a GSM modem with the serial port. I've been able to send SMS for a couple of days using the MessagingToolkit library but suddennly I'm not being able to send SMS anymore.

According to the logs this is due to a Network error. I found out that the "standard" error that I'm facing is:
CMS ERROR: 512   User abort

I found a list of error codes here http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/gsmerrorcodes/ but I can't find any further explanation on the error.

Does anyone that's familiar with GSM knows what's this error about?

When I'm initializing the modem I also get this error message from the starting configurations, it might be related to the 512 error:
2011.04.11-09.23.16: Sending: AT+COPS=0,2
2011.04.11-09.23.17: Error in command AT+COPS=0,2 :       ERROR

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that you are registered with your operator properly? You can do this by sending a AT+CREG?

Regarding the AT+COPS error message. It seems like you aren't sending enough parameters.

AT+COPS=<mode>,[<format>,<oper>[,<AcT>]]

Are you trying to manually select an operator rather than letting the modem take the default operator setup with the SIM card?

Comment: Hey man, I verified that the modem is registered on the network. I'm letting the modem take the default operator. I'll try changing the AT+COPS parameters.

Comment: It could possibly be an issue with the SMS you are sending also. Are you able to post here what you were trying to send when you got the 512 error?